# How to comple Sass with scssphp compiler cache

Tags: sass, lessphp

Less PHP (http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/) has a great method

```
function autoCompileLess($inputFile, $outputFile) {
  // load the cache
  $cacheFile = $inputFile.".cache";

  if (file_exists($cacheFile)) {
    $cache = unserialize(file_get_contents($cacheFile));
  } else {
    $cache = $inputFile;
  }

  $less = new lessc;
  $newCache = $less->cachedCompile($cache);

  if (!is_array($cache) || $newCache["updated"] > $cache["updated"]) {
    file_put_contents($cacheFile, serialize($newCache));
    file_put_contents($outputFile, $newCache['compiled']);
  }
}

autoCompileLess('myfile.less', 'myfile.css');
```

Is there any option to do same thing with http://leafo.net/scssphp/, for SASS? I can't find alternative to `cachedCompile()` with scssphp.